# how to put contents of a zip file in to an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, directory, zip

I have a zip file and I want to put contents of it in an array , actually names or directory of contents .
I have some ideas using `ZipArchive` but . . .

### is there any simple idea ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any complicated ideas:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive; 
$zipList = array();
if ($zip->open('myZipFile.zip') === true) { 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $zipList[] = $zip->getNameIndex($i); 
    } 
} else { 
    echo 'Error reading zip archive'; 
}
```

is that simple enough?

**EDIT**

A simple reading of the documentation would offer you:

```
file_put_contents($zip->getNameIndex($i), $zip->getFromIndex($i));
```

as long as the directories exist

or use the [extractTo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php) method

This is pretty well documented in the manual, and there's plenty of examples in the comments; you really shouldn't need to ask on SO for something that is documented as well as this

Comment: thanks a million , this is pretty simple :) .
I have one more problem , I checked them by extensions and collected what I wanted in that array , now I want to save them in a directory.
but these are just names .
I was wondering if you'd mind helping me .